# Pulling multiple live video streams into WPF

Tags: wpf, video-streaming

I'd like to create an app that pulls multiple live video feeds, supplied either by coax, hdmi or some other standard, into WPF for manipulation (i.e. apply a few transforms or pixel shaders) which is then output to monitor.  What would I look at to get started with this app - is there any hardware that would make things easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are pulling in standard broadcast via coax or over the air, a $100 ATSC HD TV tuner will do.  I don't have any experience with HD capture cards (I think they run for about $1000), or more specifically, cards that take in a raw HD stream.

When you install a capture device (TV tuner, webcam, capture card) in Windows, it creates a DirectShow source filter wrapper for it.  Based off what kind of hw you are targeting, determines how you create the DirectShow graph.  I have no reason to expect HD capture cards to be different than any capture card or webcam (TV tuners are slightly different).

You can use my [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com) as a base.  The web cam control may work out of the box or just require slight changes for an HD capture card.  A TV tuner would require a lot more than just this.

Comment: It's just a standard SD stream so it looks like I can do this with relatively cheap ATSC tuners.  Thanks!!