# directshow : display graph result onto wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, directshow.net

I am a beginner directshow programmer I am trying to make WPF App that contain (live feed) from certain web camera

and then I can snap a picture from this "live feed"

I defined a GraphBuilder and I did as following :

```
static void BuildGraph(IGraphBuilder pGraph)
{
    //graph builder
    int hr = 0;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 pBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
    hr = pBuilder.SetFiltergraph(pGraph);

    Guid clsid_VidCapSource = new Guid("{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}");

    //add myCam
    IBaseFilter mycam = CreateFillterByName("QuickCam Communicate Deluxe", clsid_VidCapSource);
    hr = pGraph.AddFilter(mycam, "QuickCam Communicate Deluxe");


    //add color space converter
    IBaseFilter pColorSpaceConverter3 = (IBaseFilter)new Colour();
    hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pColorSpaceConverter3, "Color Space Converter");


    //connect myCam, pColorSpaceConverter
    hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(mycam, "Capture"), GetPin(pColorSpaceConverter3, "Input"), null);

}
```

after that I build a graph :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IGraphBuilder graph = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
    BuildGraph(graph);
    IMediaControl mediaControl = (IMediaControl)graph;
    mediaControl.Run();
}
```

How can I render the output of this graph onto my WPF window

note: after build the graph the camera led indicate that the camera is capturing.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to add a SampleGrabber filter just after your video device filter to get video frames and "render" the video to a null renderer filter.

The SampleGrabber will update a buffer containing the current frame. This buffer is used to create an `InteropBitmap` and to bring the image into the WPF world. Then you can create an `ImageBrush` from the `InteropBitmap`, and use it as a `Background` for any `UIElement`.

See the following project: http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/ which do exactly what I've briefly described.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check previous questions on the topic:

- [WPF Control issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147261/wpf-control-issues)
- [Pulling multiple live video streams into WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493878/pulling-multiple-live-video-streams-into-wpf)
- [How can I use WPF MediaKit, or a similar program, for rendering from a DirectShow filter graph created with DES on to a WPF control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668990/how-can-i-use-wpf-mediakit-or-a-similar-program-for-rendering-from-a-directsho)